# Is a convex set of permutation matrices $n\times n$ ($\mathbb{P}_{n}\cap \mathbb{C}$) a singleton?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis, permutation-matrices

$\mathbb{C}$ is a closed convex set.

In detail,

$\min_{X\in\mathbb{P}_{n}\cap\mathbb{C}} f(x):= x^{T}Wx + c^{T}x$

$x:=vec(X)\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

What is wrong if I remove the $\cap\mathbb{C}$ as the below?

$\min_{X\in\mathbb{P}_{n}} f(x):= x^{T}Wx + c^{T}x$

Another statement is as the title,

If a subset of permutation matrices is convex set, is this subset Singleton, which has only one element in the set?

@Robert Israel Yeah, I also think it ends up a singleton, but it should not be like that..

@John Hughes, thanks for quick response!
Have you looked at the cases n=1,2,3 and tried writing out all the permutation matrices?

Yes, n=1, 0, 1 leads 1/2 1/3 many arbitrary convex combination element if the set have 0 and 1. So, possible answer is {0}, {1}. They are singleton.

n=2,
$P_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$ or $P_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$ The same analogy, {${P_{2}}$} with one element is only possible.

n=3, n=4... I think if there is any pairs which is not matched as (0,0) or (1,1), it causes the element which is out of Permutation matrices. I cannot get any valid subset of Permutation matrices which has over 1 element.

Have you looked at convex combinations of pairs of permutation matrices in these low-dimensional cases? Did it lead to any insight?

So the answer is the above.

Comment: The set of $n \times n$ permutation matrices is finite: there are $n!$ of them.  Any finite convex set is a singleton.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I'm having a hard time understanding why you have any doubts about the answer to this question, perhaps because you've said so little about your own thoughts on the subject. Have you looked at the cases $n = 1, 2, 3$ and tried writing out all the permutation matrices? Have you looked at convex combinations of pairs of permutation matrices in these low-dimensional cases? Did it lead to any insight? You can answer all these questions by clicking "Edit" just below your question.

Comment: $\min_{X \in \mathbb P_n \cap \mathbb C}$ and $\min_{X \in \mathbb P_n}$ seem to be fragments of  mathematical expressions: the first says the minimum over all $X$ in the intersection of $\mathbb P_n$ and $\mathbb C$ of ..., where you left out the "...".  Without the complete statement that this may be a part of, there is nothing to be "wrong".

Comment: @RobertIsrael ah, okay. This comes from Quadratic Assignment form. I would update for you to see the complete form.

Comment: @JohnHughes Btw, what does MSE mean here?

Comment: "Math Stack Exchange" -- the website on which you posted your question. :)

Comment: What is $\Bbb P_n$?

Comment: Probably the set of $n \times n$ permutation matrices (inferred from context).

Comment: Since the set of permutation matrices isn't convex, the question has an important false premise and doesn't make much sense.  In fact, $P_{n} \Cup C$ can contain 0, 1, 2, ... permutation matrices depending on $C$.

Comment: I don't see why you think "it should not be like that".  You're taking the minimum of a certain function over a finite set.  OK, it's not a convex set, but so what?  If you remove the $\cap \mathbb C$, you're allowing permutation matrices $X$ that are not in $\mathbb C$, so you might get a different answer.

Comment: @BrianBorchers No, I didn't say the set of permutation matrices is convex set. $\mathbb{P}_{n} \cap \mathbb{C}$ is a subset of the set of permutation matrices, which could be convex. I am saying, whether this subset is a singleton or not.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am trying to find the different answer.. but I cannot. I also want to think a singleton is only possible one. I may re-ask to the author of this paper. He said and explained briefly that $\cap \mathbb(C)$ is necessary. At that moment, I understood that, but I failed to verify that again. I claimed that $\cap \mathbb(C)$ is *not* necessary.